# Sketch horizontal scrolling

Tags: sketch-app, prototyping

Does the sketch prototyping functionality allow for horizontal scrolling (as with a wide table)?

I need a fixed header and fixed left side panel on mobile for wide financial data in table format. (kind of like freezing panes in google sheets).

If the native prototyping functionality cannot handle this, how would I do it?

Comment: **If** it turns out it's not possible... Keep in mind that it's not the only prototyping app out there. And seemingly all others can import Sketch projects. I'm just going to mention [ProtoPie](https://www.protopie.io/) since it works with Sketch, Figma and Adobe XD files... And it has horizontal scrolling. Of course, it's yet another expense...

Answer (score 1):

You can do horizontal scrolling in the **Protowire** plugin [this](https://protowire.com/tutorials/#scrollable-areas) video explains how.

Comment: The tool is no longer available for download :(